# How to write the contents of the current buffer back to file on each key press in Vim?

Tags: file, vim

I’d like Vim to automatically write my file as often as possible. The ideal would be every keystroke.

I need to save regularly so that my background build process will see it. It’s a makefile for a LaTeX document, and I’d like the previewer to show me a nearly up-to-date document when I’m finished typing.

#### Eventual solution

The answers below helped to make this.

```
" Choose your own statusline here
let g:pbstatusline="%F\ %y\ %l:%c\ %m"
set statusline=%F\ %y\ %l:%c\ %m

autocmd FileType tex setlocal autowriteall

" Save the file every 5 keypresses
autocmd FileType tex setlocal statusline=%!pb:WriteFileViaStatusLine()

" Save the file every time this event fires.
autocmd FileType tex :autocmd InsertLeave,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call pb:WriteFileViaStatusLine("always")

" 1 optional param: "always" is only allowed value.
let s:writefilecounter = 0
function! pb:WriteFileViaStatusLine(...)
   if s:writefilecounter > 5 || (a:0 > 0 && a:1 == "always")
      if &buftype == ""
         write
      endif
      let s:writefilecounter = 0
   else
      let s:writefilecounter = s:writefilecounter + 1
   endif

   return g:pbstatusline
endfunction
```

Comment: Whatever. These go straight into my `.vimrc` file. Thanks!

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Might want the new version. The original gives horrible errors in special files like help and quickfix.

Comment: No hacks needed in Vim 7.4+. Please see my answer using TextChanged event below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One hack is to use your status line:

```
function! WriteFile() 
  if &buftype == ""
    write
  endif
  return '%f %h%w%m%r%=%-14(%l,%c%V%) %(%P%)'
endfunction
setlocal statusline=%!WriteFile()
set laststatus=2
```

As long as the status line is visible, it's updated after each change to the file.
When updated, the `WriteFile()` function is called, which writes the file (and returns my approximation at the default status line).  With `laststatus=2`, the status line is shown even when only one window is open.

This will keep the current buffer saved after each change.

Comment: Changed this to the right answer. This is by far the best way I've heard of.

Comment: Those who wants to use rampion's semi-default formatting string in a `set statusline` command, don't forget to escape the spaces with blackslashes - I've lost nearly an hour on that!

Comment: I suggest to replace `write` with `update`: this will write file only if it has changed.

Answer (score 13):

These hacks are not needed any more. Vim can automatically write a file to disk whenever it is changed. Just add this to your $MYVIMRC:

`autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> write`

I believe you need Vim 7.4. In contrast to `autosave=1`, this will save your file *as soon as* you change it.

Answer (score 6):

There are CursorMoved and CursorMovedI autocmd events, but I don't think there's one that applies every single time you type in Insert mode.

You could also, were you so bold, rebind every single printable character in Insert mode to save and then type the character.

Comment: I think Eevee is right that CursorMoved & CursorMovedI are what you want; see this Vim tip which does something on every cursor move: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_cursor_line_after_cursor_jump

Comment: If you could move the last 2 paragraphs to the top, I would mark this correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, swap file doesn't help you much here.  Done.

Comment: Ta. I also added CursorHold and CursorHoldI

Comment: The other answer was a great answer, so had to change the one I picked. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it; that's a very clever answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Linux, you can take a look at
http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/vim-live-latex-preview/

He's using scripts and [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com)(a lightweight pdf viewer) for live preview of latex markup.
It's very fast and the best/easiest solution I have found so far.
I've been using it for quite some time now and it works great!

Answer (score 3):

Whoops!  I have been informed I forgot to mention that this usage is in the *TODO* list, and is "Coming Soon®".  I actually wanted this feature a few days ago and discovered it doesn't work yet.  Drat!

use autosave option in .vimrc (_vimrc for windows)

```
set autosave=4
```

This will save your file 4 seconds after the last change.  Setting it to one would accomplish what you're looking for.  It'll be automatic and always work.
(Simpler is better)

*TODO* ... evidently I wasn't retaining WHERE I found this when I wrote this answer long ago. Thanks @sehe

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that the source of this is (NB.:) **[`*todo.txt*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/todo.html#'autosave')**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the method I described in similar [Save file after each edit in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18121676/2656537)  question:

---

The `CursorHold` and `CursorHoldI` might help. According to docs:

```
|CursorHold|        the user doesn't press a key for a while
|CursorHoldI|       the user doesn't press a key for a while in Insert mode
```

Those events fire only **once** after inactivity and depend on `updatetime` variable (default: 4000ms). So you can:

```
:au CursorHold <buffer> :update
```

Which will update current buffer file (i.e. save only if modified) after default 4 seconds of inactivity in Normal mode.

Add autocommand for `CursorHoldI` if you want to get the same behavior in Insert mode.

---

Setting `CursorHold`,  `CursorHoldI` events along with very short `updatetime` will make vim save the file instantly after the edit.