# Save file after each edit in vim

Tags: vim

I'm constantly doing this in vim: [do something in insert or normal mode], Esc, :ws

I do this hundreds of times a day. Instead, I'd like to lose the habit and have vim save to file immediately after any change to buffer.

Everything is running off an SSD so I don't expect performance to be an issue.

Answer (score 16):

Add this simple mapping to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:w<CR>
```

to write the current buffer automatically on each `<Esc>` in *INSERT* mode.

Comment: Seems obvious, now that I think about it, but only solves half the problem. You can edit the buffer without ever entering insert mode.

Comment: You might prefer "autocmd InsertLeave * update" to a mapping.

Answer (score 6):

The `CursorHold` and `CursorHoldI` might help. According to docs:

```
|CursorHold|        the user doesn't press a key for a while
|CursorHoldI|       the user doesn't press a key for a while in Insert mode
```

Those events fire only **once** after inactivity and depend on `updatetime` variable (default: 4000ms). So you can:

```
:au CursorHold <buffer> :update
```

Which will update current buffer file (i.e. save only if modified) after default 4 seconds of inactivity in Normal mode.

Add autocommand for `CursorHoldI` if you want to get the same behavior in Insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of, other than coding it ([check out the VIM Wiki for a starting point](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-save_current_buffer_periodically)). VIMs swap file almost does what you are asking, for recovery purposes.

From the [VIM man page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html);

> The swap file is updated after typing 200 characters or when you have
>   not typed anything for four seconds

Seems like that would catch most quirks. Is there some specific problem you are trying to avoid?

Comment: I'd like to run syntastic every time I change something (by default it runs when you save) and I'd like to lose the habit of constantly saving manually. I don't like swap files because they pollute my working dir. I guess I could save every 1 second or so, but that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function for autosave: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-save_current_buffer_periodically