# Run a vim script written in python?

Tags: vim, compiler-construction

This is in reference to the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240037/recommended-build-system-for-latex) written by [Paul Biggar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104021/paul-biggar):

> After considering all these options for some time, I have settled with the following solution.
>
> - [Set vim to write continuously as I type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313323/vim-write-back-my-file-on-each-key-press).
> - Run a script in the background to build continuously, refreshing the pdf as it goes. latexmk is nearly good enough, except that it builds in place, which gets reloaded at a bad time in okular (my viewer).
>     The script is available at https://github.com/pbiggar/texbuild.
>
> Use rubber-info to get the errors and warnings from the log file. The script above saves the log file in t.log. In vim:
>
> ```
>  autocmd FileType tex set makeprg=rubber-info\ t.log
>  autocmd FileType tex set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
> ```

I want to execute [his github script](https://github.com/pbiggar/texbuild) in order to "build [LaTeX files] continuously, refreshing the pdf as it goes." Given that he doesn't exactly offer instructions how to run it, I assume this is a rather trivial procedure. However, I'm quite new at vim and know very little about programming/github in general, so I really have no clue how to start.

I've searched high and low, and have made zero progress. I'm not sure if the code is supposed to be compiled in python, then run as a script, or anything similar. I appreciate your help!

*EDIT:* As per the comments discussion, I've successfully made the script executable. But I still don't know how to run it..?

Comment: What have you tried? Assuming you made the script executable and considering line 48 reads "filename = sys.argv[1]" a simple "/path/to/texbuild filename" could be enough

Comment: Well, that's most likely the problem; I have no idea what you just said! :) I'm quite the beginner, so I don't know how to do either of the two (I assume making the script executable simply means putting it in some "correct" folder? And a "/path/to/texbuild filename" would be some type of `autocmd` to write into my `vimrc` file?)

Comment: If you're on Linux you can make the script execuable with "chmod u+x /path/to/texbuild" . And then just run it with the target file (the one you're editing in vim) as an argument.

Comment: Ah, is there an equivalent way in Windows 7? EDIT: Nevermind, http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable provides the necessary instructions for that question.

Comment: Okay, so given that I've made the script executable (as per the instructions above), how do I "run [the script] with the target file as an argument"? Is there some vim command to do this?

Comment: In Linux you would simply do `:!/path/to/script %` to run `script` with the current filename as an argument.  It probably works the same way in Windows.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you looked at http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/vim-live-latex-preview/ ? It might be an easier solution to your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top of the script states, as well as absence of `import vim` in the body clearly states that it should be run from the shell (or from vim) using

```
chmod +x /path/to/texbuild # Needed only once
/path/to/texbuild {script-args}
```

. Further exploration reveals that it expects to have one tex file as its first and only argument (the only place where `sys.argv` is mentioned is [line 48](https://github.com/pbiggar/texbuild/blob/e9e6369414de30acd2816ae7f0d3b129eb27e585/texbuild#L48)) hence it is likely that you should use the following to run it:

```
augroup AutorunTexbuild
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex :if !exists('b:runtexbuild') | call system('/path/to/texbuild '.shellescape(@%)) | let b:runtexbuild=1 | endif
    autocmd VimLeave * :call system('killall -TERM texbuild')
augroup END
```

. That assumes that you edit tex files only in one vim instance at a time. It looks like author expected you to run that script manually.