# How can I build PDF LaTeX documents with ANT (or some other build system if you prefer)?

Tags: ant, latex, makefile

The team I work for manages a large collection of technical documentation which is written in LaTeX.

Currently all the documentation we have is manually built by the editors and then checked into a version control system. Sometimes people forget to compile their documents so we have a situation where the PDF and .tex files are often out of step. Unfortunately when this happens our users find themselves reading old versions of our document.

I've managed to hack a simple script to build PDFs using Make - it's rather clumsy.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do it? Most people in our department use Eclipse + Pydev for a Python project which means we are all very familiar with this IDE. I know that Ant plays nicely with Eclipse, so might we be able to use this tool for our doc building?

So what's the best way of doing this? I hope I will not have to learn everything there is to know about a new build-system in order to automate the building of some quite simple docs.

Comment: Why do you check in stuff that is auto-generated into the repository?  That seems like an unusual practice.

Comment: We do not check in anything that's auto-generated. The documentation is mostly hand-written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an external [Ant task](http://www.dokutransdata.de/ant_latex/) for LaTeX PDF generation, though the site is in German.

To use it, download the jar to a location on your machine, then define a taskdef as follows:

```
<taskdef name="latex"    classname="de.dokutransdata.antlatex.LaTeX"  
  classpath="/path/to/ant/lib/ant_latex.jar"/>
```

Then to use it, define a target like this:

```
<target name="doLaTeX">  
  <latex  
    latexfile="${ltx2.file}"  
    verbose="on"  
    clean="on"  
    pdftex="off"  
    workingDir="${basedir}"  
  />  
</target>
```

Where ltx2.file is the file to process.

This is a link to the [howto page](http://www.dokutransdata.de/ant_latex/manual/ant_latex_howto.html) listing the parameters. If you need any more options, my German is just about passable enough to explain, maybe.

There is also a [maven plugin for LaTeX](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/maven/maven-latex-plugin/1.4.1/), but I can't find any documentation.

Comment: I saw that link, unfortunately I only speak English.

Comment: My German's not great either, but I found a link to the howto page and posted one of the examples. The parameters are at least in English so you may be ok...

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but I remember [seeing a blog post about i](http://skinn3r.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/automate-document-generation-from-latex-files-part-2/)t.

Answer (score 1):

If you know python, [this blog post might be interesting](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/09/29/using-waf-to-build-latex-documents)

**EDIT**: Also, I would assume that you're using some kind of version control system, and I can't say for sure, but I use git to manage all my latex docs, and it might be possible to use some kind of post-commit hook to execute a script to rebuild the document. This would depend on how your repository is structured... just thinking out loud, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

I went into great detail on a large number of build systems for latex in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240037/recommended-build-system-for-latex), but its slightly different in your case. I think you want rubber or latexmk. The latex-makefile seems a good idea, but only supports building via postscript, which might not be your build process.

In general, its a good idea to keep generated files outside of version control for just this reason. A good exception is when specialist build tools are not widely available, and your situation sounds similar. You might do better with a commit-hook to build automatically upon commit.

I guess I should also point out that committing something without first building it and checking it is a deadly sin, so a better solution might be to stamp that out.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a better alternative as build system compared to Ant. So I would recommend a maven-plugin to generate PDF from LaTeX sources. Have a look at [mathan-latex-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reallyinsane/mathan-latex-maven-plugin)