# php implememnt a queue with redis

Tags: php, mysql, redis

I wrote a very simple queue using redis, but I think my implementation is bad, so I want to ask for a better solution. Below is a simple flow chart of my problem.

1. some program push data into a redis list
2. a php program loop forever, check if the list if empty, if not empty then pop the nodes in the list into MySQL.

Step 1 is fine, but I have used `while (true)` in step 2, which can cause a lot of CPU waste. Any good way that can do pop operation when the list is not empty?

Comment: will `while(true)` really cause CPU waste? What do you mean by cpu waste?

Comment: You can add sleep() to your loop

Comment: When loop forever the cpu usage will be very high, and sleep() is a solution, but any smater way that can detect if the list is empty?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the easiest solution:

```
while (true) {
 if ($res = fetch(data)) {
  //do your staff
 } else {
  sleep(10);
 }
}
```

But long running PHP script may cause memory leaks, so the best way might be cronjob, with script like this:

```
//do not forget to check if process is already running, not to run duplicate processes.
```

you can try this solution:
[Checking if process still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111406/checking-if-process-still-running)

```
while ($res = fetch(data)) {
 //do your staff
}
```

Comment: I hate crons, so I'll try using another program to check if this php program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Do a cron job instead a infinite loop for the step 2

Answer (score 0):

set cron job to periodically check list and pop values into your MySql tables.  I read one of your comments that said you did not prefer cron jobs, so consider perhaps what I term a `'poor mans cron'` which is a misnomer, because the only cost of a cron job is, well server access...

Just set a time value and a threshold.  `if(now() - timeValue > threshold){` do your pop to MySql thing...

it is a rare case that you want infinite loops in php, imho.  here is some discussion: [When are infinite loops are useful in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765733/when-are-infinite-loops-are-useful-in-php)

Comment: I hate cron because it's hard to maintain a lot of cron jobs, I prefer doing the job by program not system, like using laravel's schedule. And your threshold is similar to sleep();

Comment: no no no, the major difference is that if the threshold is not met, then the conditional logic isnt executed.  The check to see if a particular time has passed is not the same as have PHP -completely stop processing- for a period of time.  sleep can cause a hang.  Perhaps in the case of 10 seconds, sleep may be ok.  I would still avoid.