# how to use pylint in vim

Tags: linux, vim, sed, pylint

I do not want to install another plugin, like pylint.vim,

And today, I decide to use vim edit python instead of pydev which is a eclipse plugin. But I got issues.

I have add this in my vimrc

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py !pylint <afile>
```

but pylint does not contains filename in output

```
************* Module mymodule
E: 22: invalid syntax

shell return 2
```

so it can not jump to the line 22 , so I use sed change the output

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py !pylint <afile> | sed 's/^\(\w*\):\s*\([0-9]\+\)/<afile>:\2: \1: /g'
```

it returns:

```
mymodule.py:22: E: : invalid syntax
```

but without shell return 2 by vim. so it still can't jump to that line. vim consider it as compile successfully

========================= new comment ===========
[Call a function in Vim’s `autocmd` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766336/call-a-function-in-vims-autocmd-command)

I think maybe I should use make command and set makeprg, so I use below config

```
autocmd FileType python let &makeprg='pylint <afile> | sed s/^\(\w*\):\s*\([0-9]\+\)/<afile>:\2: \1: /g'
autocmd BufWritePost *.py make
```

when I save, vim returns:

```
************* Module count
E:  3: invalid syntax
(1 of 2): ************* Module count
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Auto commands for "*.py":
E492: Not an editor command:  sed s/^\(\w*\):\s*\([0-9]\+\)/<afile>:\2: 
\1: /g
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

why so complicated with sed which just works properly on Linux? Try the following:

```
set makeprg=pylint\ --reports=n\ --output-format=parseable\ %:p
set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
```

Comment: thanks. Just what I want. but, what's the mean of %:p. and the errorformat is a vim variable, how could it affect pylint?

Comment: `%:p` means to use the full path of the file

Comment: Great answer.  But --output-format is now a deprecated option in pylint 1.0.0.  Alternative is to use `set makeprg=pylint\ --reports=n\ --msg-template=\"{path}:{line}:\ {msg_id}\ {symbol},\ {obj}\ {msg}\"\ %:p`

Comment: Works like a charm! `$ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.4.4, 
astroid 1.3.8, common 1.1.0
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4]`

Answer (score 17):

`pylint.vim` is old, use syntastic instead:

https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Comment: Something a little more substantial than just a bare  link would get an upvote.

Comment: It protects against link rot.

Comment: The above Vim plugin is not maintained. This fork aims to keep up to date with pylint.

https://github.com/orenhe/pylint.vim

Comment: Thanks, [syntastic has many checkers](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic-checkers.txt): `Bandit`, `flake8`, `Frosted`, `mypy`, `Prospector`, `py3kwarn`, `pycodestyle`, `pydocstyle`, `Pyflakes`, `Pylama`, `Pylint`, `python`, which one is the default?

Comment: Note: synastic has been archived since September 2023, so since this post it's not actively maintained anymore. The project themselves points to its "spiritual succesor, ALE"; see https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale.

Answer (score 4):

at last I resolve it myself. I'd like share with you guys. 2 lines in vimrc.

```
autocmd FileType python let &makeprg='pylint %\|sed "s/^\(\w*\):\s*\([0-9]\+\)/%:\2:\ \1:\ /g"'
autocmd BufWritePost *.py make
```

Comment: I have use what jceb's answer

Comment: Thanks I am able to use it and looking for longer time. But I feel it should some update. can we split screen if pylint report any error. right now if it is big error and loosing this information

Comment: I am able to use it but I would like to split error if I get any error any possiblity

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use A.L.E (Asynchronous Lint Engine) https://github.com/w0rp/ale

It supports a range of python linters and formatters including **pylint**. Great thing about A.L.E  that it supports many other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays vim ships a [compiler file for `pylint`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/compiler/pylint.vim).
This means that if you have enabled filetype detection (`filetype plugin indent on`), this is already available without external plugins.

`:set makeprg?` should show you that pylint is what will be called when issuing `:make`. If it doesn't, you need to set it as the current compiler with `:compiler! pylint`.

Now, to have this working, you need to pass some arguments so pylint knows what to lint, most notably *what* you want to lint, i.e. the filename or directory to link. So to lint the current buffer, run `:make %`. To lint the current directory, run `:make .`

That same mecanism could be extended to use flake8 for example, or any linter for any kind of file. See `:h :compiler`.

Answer (score 0):

autocmd FileType python let &makeprg=‘/usr/local/bin/pylint %’

autocmd BufWritePost *.py make

autocmd FileType python let &makeprg=‘/usr/local/bin/pyflakes %’

autocmd BufWritePost *.py make

Answer (score -1):

you may want to try running epylint instead of just pylint.

epylint (shipped with pylint) is the one that is used within emacs (with flymake). It has a few changes, especially regarding path handling, see the docstring at the start of pylint/epylint.py for more information. It may help you in vim too.

Sidenote: I'm not a vim user for programming myself, but pylint.vim still seems to be a decent option. But I won't question your prerequisites.